# Attempt to reload WIC/Core.pm aborted

Tags: perl

After searching a lot, i found that the error may be coming because it found `core.pm` in two places in my `localhost/projectfolder/code/WIC` and other in `/opt/lampp/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Apache/SizeLimit`
so how could i include the `Core.pm`  of my project folder only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
use lib 'localhost/projectfolder/code/WIC'
```

Or

PERL5LIB variable to insert this path for whole project.

```
export PERL5LIB=localhost/projectfolder/code/WIC
```

which will be appended to @INC

Or

```
no lib [path-which-you-do-not-want]
```

can also be used to tell script to not look into that path for module.